# how do i upload 3gp files

Tags: 3gp

How do I upload 3gp files to my server and view it?  I was  told that I need a htaccess.

Comment: Could you be more specific?  What server do you have?  What means do you want to use to upload the files?

Comment: And what device/OS/platform/browser are you trying to upload from?

Comment: Right now I am currently making a cell phone website by using 
mobisitegalore.com. 

　I am using window xp with exploer and firefox as my browers.

I am currently using www.startlogic.com  as my server which is a unix server.

The staff informed me that I need a.htaccess file to view my 3gp videos.

Comment: Oh, in that case do what Erick said. It's probably just a matter of setting the MIME type.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently if you type :

```
AddType video/3gpp 3gp .3gp
```

inside of a .htaccess file it would help. According to [Nokia's forums](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?t=109684). Well this is if I understood correctly the question.